# Android - Can't draw a bitmap in a canvas

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I have the following code that works:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {    
    canvas.drawRect(undoButtonRectF, buttonPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(undoButtonArrow, buttonArrowPaint);
```

Anyway, when I exchange this with the following:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {        
        undoButtonBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) undoButtonRectF.width(), (int) undoButtonRectF.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas ca = new Canvas(undoButtonBitmap);

        ca.drawRect(undoButtonRectF, buttonPaint);
        ca.drawPath(undoButtonArrow, buttonArrowPaint);

        canvas.drawBitmap(undoButtonBitmap, undoButtonRectF.left, undoButtonRectF.top, buttonPaint);
```

nothing is drawn. How can this happen? Am I using bitmap in a wrong way? Please, help me!!!

Comment: Because you did it with `canvas` variable instead of your `ca` variable

Comment: this is inside a onDraw(Canvas canvas) call. I need to draw undoButtonBitmap inside canvas and I use ca just to write stuff in the bitmap. Then, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there is a coordinator error.

The error is that undoButtonRectF contains the offsets for "canvas", not for "ca", you should adjust or remove the top/left offset before you call

```
 ca.drawRect(undoButtonRectF, buttonPaint);
 ca.drawPath(undoButtonArrow, buttonArrowPaint);
```

Right ?